# Multiple wrapper react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router 1.0

I would like to have a wrapper for the admin and another wrapper for the "normal" website.

I've tried with something like this without success:

```
  <Route>
    <Route component={ AdminWrapper}>
      <Route path="/admin/order" component={ AdminOrder } />
    </Route>
    <Route component={ AppWrapper }>
      <Route path="/" component={ Home }/>
      <Route path="*" component={ NotFound }/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

Comment: What's not working? The way you've done it is correct apart from not specifying a path on your "parents".

Comment: I don't want any path on the parents. I just used It because jsx requires to be encapsulated

Comment: Did you remember to use `<Router>` at the top?

Comment: My bad. It's was working. The error was about something else...

But thanks for your help

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/